# Rule of differentiation and continuity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

If $r(x) = w_1(x)/w_2(x)$ and $w_1$ and $w_2$ are both differentiable functions doesn't that mean we can say that $r$ is differentiable so continuous?

Comment: Possible issues when $w_2(x)$ takes on the value $0$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of two differentiable functions is differentiable wherever it is defined :).
So you need to make sure $w_2 \ne 0$ in your domain, but then it's all good!